# Unable to stream response word by word or chunk

Tags: reactjs

I'm sending a stream from backend and I want to immediately show it on the frontend. But for some reason, I'm only able to the final sentence together and it is not streaming like chatGPT, word by word or by chunk

```
  .then((response) => {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");

        const streamReader = () => {
          return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
            if (done) {
              console.log("Stream ended");
              return;
            }
            const decodedChunk = decoder.decode(value);
            console.log("Received data:", decodedChunk);
            setStreamingResponse((prevResponse) =>
              prevResponse + decodedChunk
            );
            return streamReader();
          });
        };

        return streamReader();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

Console.log("decoded value") Give me following output

```
I
am

A
Right-hand batsman
```

How to show this in frontend?